# Is it possible to remap a single column, with a special character in it, with Entity Framework Code First?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a rather large table of mineral/vitamin definitions (44 columns) and every column name but one is correct. I have a column called `[Tryptophan/60]` in the SQL database table and I need to represent this in my EF DTO Object `MineralDefinition`:

```
public class MineralDefinition
{
    public int DefinitionId {get;set;}
    public string Tryptophan60 {get;set;}
    // 43 other minerals/vitamins
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot change the columns in the database. Is there any way I can remap this single column without having to write out every column? And, come to think of it, how do I remap the field anyway as it has a `/` in it?

Comment: In addition, is there any reason not to use the edmx builder? That will add the auto mapping for you.

Comment: @Morder - Usually I'm an advocate of using code generators, but I really dislike using the edmx builder. I stayed away from EF because of it, but when code first came out, I had a go and it's so much nicer. I'd rather deal with POCO objects than deal with a class diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

It looks like it isn't possible to map only **one** column and is a feature that would need to be requested to get into the next EF.

This should get you on the right direction. You'll need to using `System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration` for the EntityMap

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.Entity<Test>().MapSingleType(m => EntityMap.Row(
        EntityMap.Column(m.Tryptophan60, "Tryptophan/60")
    )).ToTable("MineralDefinition");
}
```

You might have to add `modelBuilder.IncludeMetadataInDatabase = false;` in order to avoid model change errors.

Comment: Thanks, but that still requires listing every single column. Is there no way to do it without listing all 44 columns?

Comment: I just finished talking with Jon Galloway about this issue and the basics of the conversation is that it's a feature (single column mapping) that should definitely be requested but is currently unavailable.

Comment: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-ado-net-entity-framework-ef-feature-suggestions You can vote for feature additions for Entity Framework here